# React/Redux Tools.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, redux-thunk

I'm making a simple api call to my backend to display all the tools.  I'm using Redux/Redux Thunk to handle the app's state.  On my /tools page, it is supposed to just list all the tools in the database.  It looks like it is rendering twice, as props.tools is initially null and then has the array of tools.  Unfortunately this still results in an error.  If someone could explain this behavior and how to remedy it I would appreciate it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Tools extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log('tools', this.props.tools);

    const allTools = this.props.tools.map(tool => <li>tool</li>);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>tools</h1>
        <ul>{allTools}</ul>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { tools: state.tools };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tools);
```

Comment: Please add reducers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first time reducer's initialised, it has no values for `tools`
So,you getting `tools=null` and because of this an error.

You have to set it to default value in your reducers.

In your reducers,just need to initialise the `tools` to default value.

```
const defaultState = {
   tools : []
}
const  myReducers = (state = defaultState,action)=>{
   //....other action
    default : 
     return state;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had my state in my reducer initialized to 'null', just changed it to '[]'.  It is still rendering twice though, is that the expected behavior?

Comment: yes.twice means . first time . store initialisation and second time when u r setting data. you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle to avoid unnecessary rendering.